# I move my presta-shop version-1.6.1.0 site from one server to other displaying error about database query

Tags: prestashop-1.6, server-migration

```
SELECT bc.`id_cms_block`, bc.`id_cms_category`, bc.`display_store`, ccl.`link_rewrite`, ccl.`name` category_name, bcl.`name` block_name
        FROM `ps_cms_block` bc
        LEFT JOIN `ps_cms_block_shop` bcs
        ON (bcs.id_cms_block = bc.id_cms_block)
        INNER JOIN `ps_cms_category_lang` ccl
        ON (bc.`id_cms_category` = ccl.`id_cms_category`)
        INNER JOIN `ps_cms_block_lang` bcl
        ON (bc.`id_cms_block` = bcl.`id_cms_block`)
        WHERE bc.`location` = 0
        AND ccl.`id_lang` = 1
        AND bcl.`id_lang` = 1
        AND bcs.id_shop = 1 AND ccl.`id_shop` = 1
        ORDER BY `position`
```

> Unknown column 'ccl.id_shop' in 'where clause'

and also

> Unknown column id_product in  ps_image_shop table.

I follow this step:

1. move all files from one server to another server.
2. and also import database in new server.
3. I changed database name, username and password in setting.inc.php.
4. in database, domain and domain_ssl change 'domainname.effective-internet.com' to 'www.domainname' in ps_shop_url table.

Admin side not display product list. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Error is displayin at line 765 in file classes/db/Db.php

Comment: Please edit your post in readable format.

Comment: I had this same problem. check your ps_image_shop table. does it have id_product column?? you might have to delete that entire column from the table

Comment: Can you also check the version of prestashop now on the new server and tell me what it is?

Comment: To solve the first error i add id_shop then second error generate so,to solve this error I add id_product in ps_image_shop table.if I remove this column from the table it showing error..now I can see product list on admin side and front side but still images are not showing please suggest any idea about this problem thanks.